Not redirecting to login page
We have few community sites in our org.
When we click on url of site some of the sites are getting redirected to the login page and some of the sites are opening directly with salesforce credentials.
May I know why is this happening?

If I understood it right, you mean to say that it is taking you to the Salesforce login page instead of your community site login pages.
In that case check if those sites are active, if they are Active go to the builder of the site and Publish them again. This will resolve the issue.
